# How does WordPress discard auto-draft posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to find out how auto-draft posts are discarded when the post author navigates away from the back-end editor before saving. My aim is to use the same process to discard 'draft' posts.

For example, if a user starts working on a post which is in 'draft' status, then decides to close the browser window or navigate away from the post editor, then I'd like the draft post to be discarded.

I'd be grateful if anyone has information on how 'auto-draft' posts are discarded by WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

in wp-confing

```
define ('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false);
```

Comment: How is WP_POST_REVISIONS related to auto-drafts?